# Laravel - convert array into eloquent collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, eloquent

I need to use data from an API.

I create a function:

```
    public function getItems()
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->get('https://app.example.com/api/getItems');

$vouchers = json_decode($res->getBody(), true);

dd($vouchers);

return view('api', compact('vouchers'));


}
```

and `dd($vouchers)` return me:

[image]

Now when I try to use $vouchers array with blade engine like:

```
<body>
              @foreach ($vouchers as $v)
                <p>{{$v->name}}</p>
              @endforeach
          </body>
```

I got error:

```
"Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: .... etc...
```

How I can convert array into eloquent collection.
I use the latest Laravel 5.7 version

Comment: Could you `dd($vouchers['vouchers']);` and post back the result?

Comment: The question title can be misleading for some and the way I interpreted the question title, the answer should be `new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection(<array of models>);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually your `$vouchers` is an array of arrays,

So you may want to convert your sub-arrays to objects:

You can do it simply using:

```
foreach ($vouchers['vouchers'] as $key => $value) {
    $vouchers['vouchers'][$key] = (object) $value;
}
```

.. or using collections:

```
$vouchers = collect($vouchers['vouchers'])->map(function ($voucher) {
    return (object) $voucher;
});
```

[Laravel collections documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#introduction)

Answer (score 6):

To cast an array into a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` you can use `hydrate()` method with the destination *Eloquent model*, for example:

```
$eloquentCollection = TheEloquentModel::hydrate($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because arrays have index.
you can do something like this :

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($vouchers); $i++)
    <p>{{$vouchers[$i]->name}}</p>
@endfor
```

**Update**

If each of them included another array, you can try this instead :

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($vouchers); $i++)
    <p>{{$vouchers[$i][0]->name}}</p>
@endfor
```